# Nested controller issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, ionic-framework

I don't know if my title describe well my problem but, it's what i think happen here. What am trying to do is to add facebook login to my app that i used the sidemenu ionic template and i followed the tutorial [ionic facebook integration](http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html)

It works well no issues on both browser and mobile but, when i tried to show the facebook data profile picture not in the template profile but, in the top of my side menu i got two issues.

First i need to refresh the browser so the picture show.

Second issue i get this alert `Facebook error: undefined` which is in the `profileCtrl`

i get this error when i created a `div` inside of the `menu template` and sat `ng-controller="profileCtrl"` here i think the app get a conflict because the `APPCtrl` is the controller of the `menu Template` like this:

```
templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
controller: 'AppCtrl'
```

here is the code i added to the menu template to show the picture and the user name in the top of the side menu:

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl" class="user-pro">

        <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{user.id}}/picture?width=100&height=100"/>
        <p class="text-center user-name side-btn">{{user.name}}</p>

 </div>
```

and here is the `menu template` code and how i putted my code in it :

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content class="has-header side-bg"><!-- sidebar -->
            <!-- user profile here -->
     <div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl" class="user-pro">
        <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{user.id}}/picture?width=100&height=100"/>
        <p class="text-center user-name side-btn">{{user.name}}</p>
     </div><!-- user Profile -->
     <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
      </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

I wrapped the side `menu template` with a `<div ng-controller="AppCtrl"` and do the hierarchy explained here [angular.js hierarchy controller guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) and SURE i did deleted the `controller: 'AppCtrl'` from here

```
.state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
```

but it did't work.

sorry for being long.

Comment: In the profile controller is the user info available straight away or is it asynchronously fetched?

Comment: Also does the name at least appear?

Comment: The name and the photo appear,my problem is i need to refresh. here is my controller code `controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope) {
    openFB.api({
        path: '/me',params: {fields: 'id,name'},success:function(user) {$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.user = user;});},
        error: function(error) {
            alert('Facebook error profile ProfileCtrl: ' + error.error_description);
        }
    });`i get the alert when page load then i login via facebook then i need to refresh and the name and photo appear but before when i viewed the data in the profile template i had no issues

Comment: Both require refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can answer all of your issues. I.e. The Facebook undefined error. However I can fix your photo not showing.

When using a binding in the src attribute of an image tag you should instead use ng-src.

Especially when the binding is changed asynchronously.

```
    <img ng-src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{user.id}}/picture?width=100&height=100"/>
```

Using just `src` the browser would fetch something like  "http://graph.facebook.com/UNDEFINED/picture?width=100&height=100" and when the value changes the browser will not check that and won't fetch the new image. Angular takes care of this for you. I'm guessing on refresh there is some sort of race condition that is being satisfied. Although I'm not familiar with how the Facebook library works.

Comment: that's true thank you i fixed that, but it didn't solve my main problem still get the alert and i need to refresh, but one error gone from my browser log.

Comment: Was hoping that would end the need to refresh though. Let me see if I can spot anything else

Comment: thank you and i would mention that am using special library called openFb, but im telling my problems appear after i put the div in the menu template